# Emulation of slideshow

Tags: verilog

I am doing emulation of slideshow of images in which i store pixel values in SRAM using processor and read data using VGA .It works fine when i store data in sram and read it through VGA seperately. But SRAM data is getting corrupted when i Write to it and read from it at the same time for the continous display of the image. Everything works fine in simulation but not in emulation.Is there anythings which i need to take care of during emulation?

Comment: what do you mean by emulation?

Comment: Running the verilog code on FPGA

Comment: Are you making timing closure? What do your synthesis/implementation log files say?

Comment: Yup everything works fine but the picture displayed on monitor gets corrupted ,there will be many dots on the image.I read the sram after display and the data wich i read was different from what i have stored

Comment: What does the post-synthesis/post implementation simulation look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you grant access to either the VGA output and the processor ?
If you are using a dual-port memory, read its specifications. Sometimes concurrent read and write are not handled.

I suppose that the reading operation is done pretty quickly, but at a slow rate (50 or 60 Hz, depending on the display), so a possible solution might be to lock the access to the memory during read, so the processor does not write during read. Like a bus with an arbiter.

Comment: Yup i have done that but i wanted to write when the vga is reading so that the display will show the new image and it should continously display the image.I think the write cycles happen at slower rate  than the read cycles.I have created the same situation in simulation but the data which i write into sram is not corrupted when vga reads data from that. I have tried it and only the alternative image data is getting corrupted.Is there any emulation problems like because of difference in speed of signals or SRAM chip may swollow write cycles?

Comment: It depends on how the memory model is written. During synthesis (what you call emulation) the tool try to understand what you've written. In case of dual port memory, a mismatch between simulation and synthesis can happen depending on how you've handled the 'read during write' operation in your model. Have you written your memory model yourself or are you using a constructor related IP.